# How to call swift method from objective c

Tags: ios, swift, callback, objective-c-blocks, bridge

I have created my custom dialog in swift with xib file 
Now i want to use that dialog from objective c file 
I am able to show the dialog but i cannot able to listen click event of button

My Swift code is like

```
public class CustomVerificationDialog:UIView,UITextFieldDelegate
{
     ///Othere stuffs
      var onClickRightButton : ((_ text1:String , _ text2:String ) -> Void)? = nil //This method is called when button is clicked

     @IBAction func onClickBtnRight(_ sender: Any)
        {
            if self.onClickRightButton != nil
            {
                self.onClickRightButton!(editTextOne.text ?? "",editTextTwo.text ?? "")
            }

        }
 }
```

Now i am able to get the click event in swift like

```
dialogForVerification.onClickRightButton =
            { (text1:String,text2:String) in
                }
```

But i dont know how to listen it in objective c

```
CustomVerificationDialog *dialogVerification =  [CustomVerificationDialog showCustomDialog];
???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
[dialogVerification setOnClickRightButton:^(NSString * _Nonnull text1 , NSString * _Nonnull text2 ) {

}];
```

Here is a [Demo](http://www.mediafire.com/file/dpdm2f20ddl8f9t/vjvjvhbjv.zip/file)

Comment: No its not working it says No visible @interface for 'CustomVerificationDialog' declares the selector 'setOnClickRightButton:'

Comment: Did you tested it ???? **set** is appended for properties , see the attached demo

Comment: Yes its working after clean and rebuild the project. first time its show me the compile time error but after rebuild error goes thanks Sh_Khan..

Answer (score 0):

In order to access any swift class and its methods/properties in objective-c file, you need to mark that class/method/property with @objc. Then you need to import "TargetName-Swift.h" in your objective-c file in order to access swift code in objective-c file. Here is the code snippet which hopefully solve your problem:

Replace your swift class with:

```
    @objc public class CustomVerificationDialog:UIView,UITextFieldDelegate

    {

        @objc var onClickRightButton : ((_ text1:String , _ text2:String ) -> Void)? = nil //This method is called when button is clicked

        @IBAction func onClickBtnRight(_ sender: Any)
        {
           if self.onClickRightButton != nil
           {
           self.onClickRightButton!(editTextOne.text ?? "",editTextTwo.text ?? "")
           }

        }
        //other code goes here
    }
```

and In your objective-c file (i.e. viewController)

```
#import "YourTargetName-Swift.h"

...................
................
CustomVerificationDialog *dialogVerification =  [CustomVerificationDialog showCustomDialog];
[dialogVerification setOnClickRightButton:^(NSString * _Nonnull text1 , NSString * _Nonnull text2 ) {

}];
// other code here
.................
..................
```